# MQTT Connection lost on AWS IOT core when I create a thing and certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I am new to AWS IoT core and I have just created one simple thing and created certificate and also attached a policy to certificate and  my thing.

when I go to my certificate page I can see it has my policy attached to it and also my thing attached to it. (the policy has all resource * and has all IoT:* actions)

[image]
[image]

I think I am doing all correctly but when on AWS IoT portal I go to test, I always get "Mqtt connection lost. Reconnect." on nitrification panel.
[image]

I have also come up with some python codes and used the private key and certificate which I created from above but again my client program can not connect to AWS IoT.

I am not sure why the test doesn't work at all and I always get "Mqtt connection lost"?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using the Azure IoT portal to test connectivity. I have always found it easier to use a standalone MQTT client. e.g. https://mqttfx.jensd.de/

Comment: sorry for my typo it is aws portal.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use mgttfx. I even cant connect to end point gateway when I úse 'Test' panel in AWS IoT core.

Comment: May I have the screeshot of the AWS IoT -> Test page where you get the error?

Comment: I have added the screen showing the error.

Comment: "It doesn't make sense to use mgttfx". It made sense if you were trying to use the Azure IoT portal to test connectivity. I still recommend using a third party client to test to rule out some config on your account.

Comment: @Luckylukee - My experience says that your MQTT connection error has nothing to do with misconfiguration of your IoT devices/certificates/policies.

Answer (score 0):

@Luckylukee -

Thanks for the screenshot!

My experience says that your MQTT connection error has nothing to do with the configuration of your IoT devices/certificates/policies.

Reason I say it is.. **without any devices created in AWS IoT, you should still be able to click on 'Test' button and subscribe to topics without issues.**

The error you reported is something very "core" between AWS IoT Test Tool and AWS IoT Server Endpoint (specific to your AWS account).

Can you try these?

1. **Use a different browser** (not in private-mode) to do the same test.
2. **Use a different AWS Account** (at least temporarily) to see if this TEST button works there! (Because, new AWS account will get you a new IoT Core Endpoint).

Good Luck!